# How can I manage bi-directional relationships with apollo client in-memory cache?

Tags: apollo-client

I have the following simple schema. A self-referencing `Thing` that forms a tree of values.

```
type Thing {  
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  parent: Thing
  children: [Thing]
}
```

My back-end is smart enough to update both sides of the bi-directional relationship when either are mutated.

However, if I use `@apollo/client` (v3) and cache the responses from those mutations, the local cache isn't smart enough to update both ends. The same is true if I manually update one end of either relationship in the local cache.

I considered that maybe a field policy would have an elegant solution to this, however if I create a policy for when I write to field `parent`, the function doesn't have access to the other values being written, so I can't get the current id to add to the parent's children. Nor can I do the opposite.

I tried writing an update function for the mutation, which patches children when parent is set - this works, however the optimistic result is ignored even though it's the same shape.

I'm at my wits end with `@apollo/client`...

Does anyone have an elegant way to solve this scenario that is compatible with optimistic results?